# BibTex puts a comma after every citation

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

This is driving me crazy since I cannot find a way to solve it.

BibTex keep putting a comma after all the citations in my document, but everything is ok in the bibliography.

It looks like this:

```
[Author (2009),]
[Author et al. (2008),]
```

In my preable I'm using the following packages to manage the bibliography:

- \usepackage[sort]{natbib}
- \usepackage{bibunits}

I also tried different templates, but the comma still is there.

Am I missing something?

Complete example below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} %draft can be a useful option for quick compile

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bbm}   
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % include images
\usepackage{thesis}                     % Stylefile
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Letters like ä ü ö ß
\usepackage{epstopdf}                       % include of .eps files in 
pdflatex, requires a ghostscript installation
\usepackage{packages/psboxit}
\usepackage[english]{babel}                 % Lineending in english
\usepackage{blindtext}                      % Lorem Ipsum, blindtext
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}  %\todo, \missingfigure und 
\listoftodos (siehe unten für eigene Definitionen)


\usepackage[sort]{natbib}                   % citation style
\usepackage{bibunits}                       % include multiplfe reference

\makeindex
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}
\begin{document}

\input{chapter/1.tex}
\input{chapter/2.tex}

\chapter{Bibliography}
\bgroup
\bibliographyunit
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle/noon} % global bibliography
\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{}
\renewcommand\bibname{~}
\bibliography{bib/mybib} % global bibliography
\egroup


\end{document}
```

Bibliography file entry below:

```
@InCollection{Dietz2004,
author    = {Jan L. G. Dietz and Terry A. Halpin},
title     = {Using {DEMO} and {ORM} in Concert: {A} Case Study},
booktitle = {Advanced Topics in Database Research, Vol. 3},
publisher = {Idea Group},
year      = {2004},
editor    = {Keng Siau},
pages     = {218--236},
bibsource = {dblp computer science bibliography, https://dblp.org},
biburl    = {https://dblp.org/rec/bib/books/idea/siau2004/DietzH04},
}
```

The **.bst** file I'm using is [this](https://textuploader.com/1llrt)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. My impression is that what you call "entries in my document" are what are more commonly known as "citation call-outs"  (of the author-year type, to be precise). Is this impression correct? Please advise.  Please also state which citation management package, or packages, you load.

Comment: How do you cite in those entries in your document? What citation-related packages do you load. In theory the `.bst` file you use should have no bearing on whether or not you get to see commas in that position in the citation, but I can imagine situations where a bibstyle that is incompatible with your citation package may cause issues similar to this one. Please show us a short example document that reproduces what you are seeing with as little code as possible (an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I just updated my question.

Comment: Can you please show us a short example document of what exactly you are doing? I can't get `thesis.bst` to work without errors. It should be noted that the `thesis.bst` you are linking to seems to be part of the `mlbib` package (which I had never heard of until today), so you may have to use it together with `\usepackage{mlbib}` and it may not be compatible with `natbib` and `sortbib`. At this point it may be easier to switch to a different style than `thesis.bst`. Is there any particular reason why you are using it?

Comment: Please give a *complete* example, LaTeX source and bibliography file. Preferrably as small as you can manage.

Comment: Maybe now I provided all the useful information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seem to be some line breaks in the code that aren't there in the original (in particular some comments seem to have been broken into, which will lead to errors when run as is). We also don't have your files `chapter/1.tex` and `chapter/2.tex`, so the example is not immediately compilable for us. What is `bibstyle/noon`? I though you used `thesis.bst`? Anyway, if `bibstyle/noon` is anything like the `thesis.bst` you linked it is only half compatible with `natbib`. It needs to be used with `\usepackage{mlbib}`.

Comment: Actually my link to the .bst was completely wrong, sorry. I updated the post with the right one.

Comment: Since I can't run your longer file due to the problems explained above I ran this truly minimal example: https://gist.github.com/moewew/a9e0b90d540f6498bc1efe9b622e27e6. BibTeX complains about `You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry Dietz2004`, which is an error that should be looked at (unfortunately, I don't have time for that right now, `.bst` files have a very peculiar programming language), but if I ignore the error for a moment (which one really shouldn't, but ...), then I get "Dietz und Halpin (2004)" from `\citet` as I would expect. ...

Comment: ... How do you cite in your document? What does the MWE produce for you? (If the MWE does not reproduce the error for you, can you add enough code from your real document so that it does?)

Comment: Ok I found that the error was related to the line 1558 of that file. Looking online for other people having the same problem, it seems that the file has a programming language and when this error happens means that there is an error inside the file. So it is not a configuration error, but a mistake inside that file.

Comment: Are you implying that fixing the error in the bst file has solved the pesky comma issue? Please advise.